# What does ZTV,ZTS,ZTI mean in the result of gdb x/nfu "vtable_address"?

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, vtable, name-mangling

### 1. the code

```
class Parent {
 public:
  virtual void Foo() {}
  virtual void FooNotOverridden() {}
};

class Derived : public Parent {
 public:
  void Foo() override {}
};

int main() {
  Parent p1, p2;
  Derived d1, d2;
}
```

### 2. gdb command

```
(gdb) x/300xb 0x400b30
```

`0x400b30` is the first address of d's vtable.

### 3. gdb result

```
0x400b30 <_ZTV7Derived>:    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x400b38 <_ZTV7Derived+8>:  0x80    0x0b    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x400b40 <_ZTV7Derived+16>: 0x60    0x0a    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x400b48 <_ZTV7Derived+24>: 0x70    0x0a    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x400b50 <_ZTS7Derived>:    0x37    0x44    0x65    0x72    0x69    0x76    0x65    0x64
0x400b58 <_ZTS7Derived+8>:  0x00    0x36    0x50    0x61    0x72    0x65    0x6e    0x74
0x400b60 <_ZTS6Parent+7>:   0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x400b68 <_ZTI6Parent>: 0x70    0x20    0x60    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

### 4. question

What does **_ZTV**, **_ZTS**, **_ZTI** mean in `<_ZTV7Derived>`, `<_ZTS7Derived>`, `<_ZTI6Parent>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the way the C++ symbol names are mangled by your development platform. You can use the `c++filt` command line tool from [GNU Binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/) to find out:

```
$ c++filt _ZTV7Derived
vtable for Derived
$ c++filt _ZTS7Derived
typeinfo name for Derived
$ c++filt _ZTI6Parent
typeinfo for Parent
```

More specifically, it is the mangling defined by the Itanium or IA-64 C++ ABI which is also used on x86_64 (because the [System V Application Binary Interface - AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) says so in section 9.1 titled "C++"). See [section on "Virtual Tables and RTTI"](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-special-vtables) in the Itanium C++ ABI for the exact mangling details.